# Is it feasable to configure Bean property in Spring through API call?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, javabeans

I am working on a project(legacy) that uses spring, now there is a bean which has properties but now we wanna configure those properties through a API call because the user can change those property anytime or add new properties.

Currently, we have to hardcode those requests so we want to automate them somehow, is there a way we can configure bean properties through a API call ?

On a side Note :- 
A problem along side this approach would be that for each request it would require to set the bean through API request which will use **request bean scoping** as per https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html am I right or this is not feasible ?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reloading-properties

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'use request scoping'. The scopes of existing beans won't suddenly change

Comment: @crizzis I was referring that for each request to service the instance of bean would be new which would be updated one !